# Jquery Validate Depends changing rule value of minimum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript

```
dollars: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                min:{ 
                    depends: function(element) {
                        if($('#method option:selected').text() == "Cash Deposit"){
                            return 20;
                        } else if($('#method option:selected').text() == "Wire Transfer"){
                            return 200;
                        }
                        else{
                            return 20;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ,
                max: maximumDA,
                unique: true
            },
```

HTML

```
<select class="required" id="method" name="method" required>
        <option value="deposit">Cash Deposit</option>
        <option value="wire">Wire Transfer</option>
        <option value="cbymail">Cash by Mail</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to make the minimum dollar amount change when a different option is selected. The depends does not work as is. I have a feeling I will have to create my own rule to get this to work, I am just curious to know if their is a way for depends to function correctly like this.

**EDIT:**

My Solution:

In order for the min amount to be dynamically changed, I don't think you can use a depends function to change a value of the rule, only the on off.

I simply removed and added the rules to make it work as I needed.

```
$('#method').change(function(){
    if($('#method option:selected').text() == "Cash Deposit"){
         $('#dollars').rules("remove","min");
         $('#dollars').rules("add",{min:20});
    }
    else if($('#method option:selected').text() == "Wire Transfer"){
         $('#dollars').rules("remove","min");
         $('#dollars').rules("add",{min:200});
    }
    else{
         $('#dollars').rules("remove","min");
         $('#dollars').rules("add",{min:20});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should do when (events)change will happen in select tag , return that value.then only function will work.

if  function inside of dollars.min it code does't know when it will be call.

```
 var minAmount;
    $('#method').change(function(){
        if($('#method option:selected').text() == "Cash Deposit")         {  minAmount=20;   }
        else if($('#method option:selected').text() == "Wire Transfer")   {  minAmount=200;  }
        else                                                              {  minAmount=20;   }
        alert(minAmount);
    });
```

now `assign` minAmount value to `dollars :{ min : minAmount }`

```
      dollars: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            min:{ depends: minAmount },
            max: maximumDA,
            unique: true
        },
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Alert showed correct amount, but the depends did not change the value. In fact, the min ruling doesn't work initially.

Comment: why you are using depends in dollars.min   use minAmount value like this `min : minAmount`

Comment: When i just use min: minAmount, it does not recognize the dynamic change when changing options. It remains the initial minAmount and does not change.

Comment: check your console.log .

Comment: console doesn't show any errors. I don't think you can dynamically change a rule value without removing and adding again.

Comment: might be depends is optional(I think that).then only i said this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function returnValue() {
    var theValue;
    if ($('#method option:selected').val() == "deposit") {
        theValue = 20;
    } else if ($('#method option:selected').val() == "wire") {
        theValue = 200;
    } else {
        theValue = 20;
    }
    var variable = {
        dollars: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            min: {
                depends: theValue
            },
            max: maximumDA,
            unique: true
        }
    };
    return variable;
}
$('#method').change(function () {
    returnValue();
});
returnValue();
```

Note that I made some changes to your `dollars` property for testing purposes.

---

**ALTERNATIVE:**

You can use:

```
function returnValue() {
    if ($('#method option:selected').val() == "deposit") {
        return 20;
    } else if ($('#method option:selected').val() == "wire") {
        return 200;
    } else {
        return 20;
    }
}
```

... and then call the function via:

```
min: {
        depends: returnValue()
     },
```